# No sound on bluetooth headphone in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, audio, bluetooth, speakers

Yesterday, I updated my Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04. As usual, I connect my Bluetooth headphone to my PC and they got connected successfully, but even if I select my headphone as output device, I got the sound through PC speakers.

But later, I notice that I'm able to hear warning sounds (like terminal beep sound) through my headphone but not all sounds.

I tried to switch audio output configuration between A2DP sink and HSP/HFP, but it still didn't work.

Later, I think that its application based that terminal is able to produce sound through Bluetooth device but other application doesn't,
so it tries to play an mp3 file through terminal with ffplay and it worked, but still it's not working for other applications (Firefox, Chrome and vlc).

Comment: speaker-test : this command works fine and produce sound on Bluetooth device

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So, finally answering my own question.

problem seems that Ubuntu doesn't change all the audio sources to the bluetooth device
you can install 'pavucontrol' to change output medium for all applications.

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

for more details refer [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232159/ubuntu-20-04-no-sound-out-of-bluetooth-headphones#answer-1233846)
answer.

Comment: pavucontrol is a graphical frontend for pulseaudio. The first answer actually mentions the menu from pavucontrol.

Comment: And unset the headphone as fallback device. Set some other device as fallback.

Answer (score 22):

This is related to incompatibilities between config files used in 18.04 and 20.04. The solution is as easy as:

```
mv ~/.config/pulse/ ~/.config/pulse.old
pulseaudio --k && pulseaudio --start
```

Original answer in: https://askubuntu.com/a/1243890/37739

Comment: It worked for AirPods Thank you so much.

Comment: This also works on Ubuntu 21.10 (impish)

Comment: The scond command gives `E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such process`

Answer (score 10):

Yes I had the same problem when I upgraded to 20.04.  The bluetooth speaker would connect fine but then not convey the sound from a streaming movie or online radio.   It had worked seamlessly before then.  So based on this and other posts I read I installed pulse audio.  It was still not obvious to me what to do b/c all the "output" devices were configured fine in pulse audio in system settings etc. Turns out I had to go to "Playback" on the top bar menu of pulse audio and then under Firefox (the browser I am using) I had to change the setting to the bluetooth speaker.
Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

For the references, I had a similar problem as the OP and all the pulse audio settings were just fine. In my case, I needed to increase the sound volume with buttons on the headphones. The thing that got me is that in android/win the buttons would change the system volume and in ubuntu headphones seem to have their own independent volume state.

Answer (score 0):

No computer genius here and after hours of trying to install/reinstall etc from all solutions above, my solution wound up being that Chrome Remote Desktop messed things up. I removed all rdp .confd files. Everything works again..
Just in case that helps anyone.